# Definition of a reverse trap

Tags: tropes, terminology

I am confused at how people describe gender roles and their trope classification in anime. I understand that traps are characters appearing to be girls but are actually guys. One of my favorite traps of all time is Steins;Gate's [Ruka Urushibara](http://steins-gate.wikia.com/wiki/Ruka_Urushibara).

However, I don't get what "reverse traps" are. Are they appearing to be traps but are actually legit girls (a trap trap)? Or a character that initially appears to be a boy, but is actually a girl (a girl trap)? For clarity, consider what you would call [Charlotte (Charles) Dunios](http://is.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Dunois) from Infinite Stratos.

[image: charles] [image: charlotte]

**EDIT:** This post is not intended to be offensive to other genders in any way, the naming convention of "traps" pertain to fictional characters in anime/manga only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A traditional 'trap' is a boy disguised as a female. Note that this is ***not*** simply boys who look feminine, but characters who are pretending to be the opposite sex or who are presumed to be by the narrative of the medium.

**Example 'traditional' trap:**

Maria from Maria✝Holic

[image]

& Steins;Gate's Ruka Urushibara (as you mentioned earlier)

**Not a trap:** Ryuunosuke Akasaka (The Pet Girl of Sakurasou)

[image]

A 'reverse trap' is simply the opposite - A female character pretending to be a male one. This is why Charlotte falls under this category. (Until she is outed to be a female). Similar to above, characters who are masculine are not strictly reverse traps.

**Example 'reverse' trap:**

Haruhi Fujioka - Ouran Highschool Host Club

[image]

**Not a reverse trap:** Yū Kashima from Nozaki-Kun

[image]

Comment: Aah, so they should either be pretending or otherwise presumed by the audience. I've always thought Kashima was a reverse trap. Thanks, that cleared it up :)

Comment: No problem :) that's why they're 'traps' I suppose

Answer (score 7):

A reverse trap, also known as a Bifauxnen (a portmanteau of Bishōnen and faux, meaning false in French), is simply a girl who resembles a boy. Conversely, what is commonly referred to as a "trap" by the English speaking audience simply refers to a boy who has the qualities of a girl, or otherwise known as a Bishōnen.

Charolotte Dunois would be a reverse trap using these definitions.

Sources:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Bifauxnen?from=Main.ReverseTrap
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Bishonen

Comment: "Bifauxnen" is read as "beef" + [-ounen] from "shounen" :)

Comment: Bif aux nen? Sounds French.

Comment: /Bee-fow-nen/ ? It's the first time I've heard this. Learned something today, thanks :)